# In WordPress database why is the GUIDs different than live URLs?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, url, guid

For example, when I query for item "OSr1" from wp-posts, I get a post with this GUID:
http://www.XZY.com/?post_type=data-sheet&p=2439

But the live link of the same item is like this:
http://www.XZY.com/wp-content/themes/xzy/pdf/OSr1.pdf

When I enter the GUID on the browser I get to an almost empty page.

How do I get the live URLs of each item (and not the GUIDs) from the database?

Comment: The answer to why is because the live URLs are subject to change due to the URL scheme being customizable and the slug being editable at any time. The GUIDs use the post ID which is always fixed and unique for each individual post.

Answer (score 0):

The permalink ("slug") is stored in the database in the table wp_posts

```
SELECT `post_name` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `ID` = "2439"
```

Or as a WordPress-function:

```
$link = get_post_permalink(2439);
```

In the loop it is enough to do:

```
$link = get_post_permalink();
```

Kind Regards!

Tom